# How to compare a string/char in java and putting symbols between the strings on it if its not equal?

Tags: java

How can I compare a string like:

```
S1 = [ABCDC]
S2 = [ABDC]
```

And comparing the S1 to S2 and the output should be like

```
Soutput = [AB-DC]
```

Like the C in the middle will be gone?

Another example:

```
S1 = [AXBXCXD]
S2 = [ABC]
Soutput = [A-B-C--]
```

Comment: You should maybe look at how [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is calculated.

Comment: This looks like the Levenshtein distance indeed. But I think whay you are looking for is simpler, since you seem to want to check only the deletions present in the second string. Have you tried something to achieve what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is suitable for your needs.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(helper("[ABCDC]", "[ABDC]"));
    }
    private static String helper(String s1, String s2) {
        var chs1 = s1.toCharArray();
        var chs2 = s2.toCharArray();
        var index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < chs1.length; i++) {
            if (index >= chs2.length || chs2[index] != chs1[i]) chs1[i] = '-';
            else index++;
        }
        return new String(chs1);
    }
}
```